# DD command included directories

Tags: filesystems, backup, dd, directory-structure, disk-image

I'm learning the `dd` command in Linux. For test purposes, i initiated this command:

```
 sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/media/some_remote_host/stuff/myImage.img
```

I know that dd is for taking an image of the given disk/drive. But I'm curious whether it includes mounting folders according to Unix file structure [(file structure)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), such as /mnt or /media. Tried to look it up but couldn't find it. And if it includes /mnt and /media directories, does it mean it can potentially stay in infinite loop ? Because it'll index and start storing the contents of /media folder whilst writing to it. Or actual writing of `*.img` occurs when all folders are scanned and taken to the memory.

TL;DR: Does `dd` command include /mnt and /media folders into the image ?

Hope you can enlighten me on these questions. Thank you.

Device specs:

- Raspbian OS 32 bit, single drive (SD card).

Comment: for this taks you are supposed to have at least two disks (sd cards). what disks (sd cards) does your system have?

Comment: That' s the thing, i only have one sd card plugged in (as system drive). As you can see on the parameter of dd (of=/media/some_remote_host/stuff/myImage.img) I'm directly sending it to some shared network location.

Comment: I take it that this remote location is a mounted smb share, is that right?

Comment: Exactly. SMB share, which is NAS drive on my network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dd doesn't know anything about mounts or folders or unix file structure in filesystems.  dd only knows about raw data and a few trivial transformations of raw data and data blocks.  It was originally designed to read and write data from or to block devices (including disks and tapes) and could handle changing the structure of that data back and forth between blocked and streamed data and do some trivial character transformations and padding adjustments.

Running dd if= on the device of a writable mounted filesystem is dangerous, as that filesystem can change while dd is reading it.  Blocks dd has already read may be changed (and changes not seen by dd) at the same time blocks it hasn't read are changed, and the results will be a corrupt image of the filesystem on output.

Since dd is reading from a block device of (presumably) fixed size, and reading it without any knowledge of the underlying filesystem, if you are writing the output to a file in the same filesystem, it won't be an infinite loop, but it increases the likelihood and severity that your output image will be a corrupt filesystem.

As filesystems mounted on directories are not part of the parent filesystem (but the (empty) directories are), they will not be in the dd output image (but the directories themselves will be, including files that might be under the mount point if it wasn't empty before mounting).

Answer (score 2):

dd will read from the if (input file) and dump it to the of (output file), it will be a binary copy of the "if". These files can be filesystem files, filesystems themselves, raw devices, etc. This command will not make anything from the data structures that reside in the "if", if it is a filesystem it willl copy it, regardless if the operating system recognizes it. However, it is not recommended to run it with a mounted filesystem device (say if=/dev/sdb3).

Since it is a bit by bit copy, the dd command will not recognize when it reaches the mounting point of your remote share, so, no infinite loop, but I concurr with @user10489, it is dangerous.

If you are trying to backup your root filesystem, I'd recommend to do it in another system (extracting your card) or booting from another card and make your backup to a remote location or to an img file located in your new root filesystem.

Comment: Appreciate the warning. But what if i really have to hot-backup, without halting or shutting down the system ? Are there some concerns that i have to watch for ?

Comment: why some folder (contents in files) are NOT copied ? It seems tha it is blind to folder contents... I always believed it copied all, but the result tells it doesn't.

Comment: maybe the folders are symbolic links in the original container? dd does not interpret the "inside" of the file it is copying, just a bit by bit copy.